# Count rows from a seperate query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, rowcount

Ok I have tried searching for the answer to this and I just can't seem to find it. I am using SQL Server 2012. I am pulling data that will be going to a flat file. At the start and end of the flat file I need a header and footer with specific data. My issue comes in the footer in that I need the row count from the data set. Right now I have my query set up as such. This is simplified for the purpose of just trying to get the rowcount.

```
select 'header'
union
select mytable.data
from mytable
union
select 'footer'+convert(varchar(4),ROWCOUNT)
```

So the query works as needed for the purpose of the flat file I just have to populate ROWCOUNT with the numbers of rows from mytable.data.

expected output

```
Header|04||160119|||2.0|160119||
D|||||...
D|||||...
Footer|ROWCOUNT||blank||
```

UPDATE:
So wrote the code as such

```
select 'header'
union all
select mytable.data
from mytable
union all
select 'footer'+convert(varchar(4),@@Rowcount)
```

And it started working. Not entirely sure why @@Rowcount started working now when it wasn't early but it works now. Thank you all for helping me work through this.

Comment: I added that the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this using `CTE` -

```
;With dataCTE
AS
(
    select data, COUNT(*) over() as RowCnt
    from mytable
),
footerCTE
AS
(
    select 'footer'+convert(varchar(4),RowCnt) as data from dataCTE
)
select 'header' AS data
union
select data from dataCTE
union
select data from footerCTE
```

Comment: I tried this method. Using just union gives me all the data i need but the header does not stay at the top. If I do union all the header stays at the top but the footer is duplicated 125 times

Answer (score 2):

Your query would look like this:

```
select 'header'
union
select mytable.data
from mytable
union
select 'footer '+CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) AS VARCHAR(16));
```

Comment: I would however use UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Comment: UNION will return the distinct value, so duplicates will not be included in the body. They will however be counted in the footer

Comment: the middle query does have a distinct being run so union or union all would still pull the same results. The Union is just to add the header and footer

Comment: @CalebJohnson UNION will check explicitely for duplicates and remove them, UNION ALL will not. UNION ALL will perform better than the UNION.

Comment: @CalebJohnson Also if your middle query is complex, you are better off writing it as a CTE (`;WITH cte AS (<your query>) ...`) and using the CTE in the SELECT statement, rather than copying the whole middle query to get the COUNT in the last query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
     with cte
    as
    ( select 'header' as h
union
select mytable.data as h
from mytable
    )
    select * from cte
    select 'footer'+convert(varchar(4),@@ROWCOUNT)
```

Comment: received this error Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'cte'.

Comment: Edited,my test data contained columns,but while pasting I took your data.corrected now

Comment: So I took out a lot of your code to try sometime else. But left 'footer'+convert(varchar(4),@@ROWCOUNT) And all of sudden it started working How I wanted it too... I am not sure at all why @@Rowcount was not working before

Comment: @CalebJohnson: But this script gives you the count of your table records including `'header'` records which is not your actual table record !! Another thing is above query gives two result set rather than one